# C++, error when finding length of an array, only when using SEPARATE FUNCTION

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

when I'm finding the length of an array, it keeps returning 2 if it is used in a seperate function. If i find the length in the main function however, it finds the length properly. If anyone can help, thank you so much. I'm a c++ noob

```
void printLength(int inputArray[]) {
        cout << "This is my value when finding the length in ANOTHER function: " << sizeof(inputArray)/sizeof(int) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int testArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };


    printLength(testArray);

    cout << "This is my value when finding the length in the main function: " << sizeof(testArray)/sizeof(int) << endl;
}
```

This is my output

```
This is my value when finding the length in ANOTHER function: 2
This is my value when finding the length in the main function: 6
```

Comment: How would the inputArray in function know the number of elements you have in your actual array? Because you only pass base address of the array.

Comment: arrays are pointers, you are passing then a point to a int as parameter

Comment: Arrays are not pointers!  But there are no array function arguments.